# Pass boolean from rails controller to javascript for use in conditional

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have a form in a bootstrap modal that is being processed using ajax. If the form validates it closes the modal or shows the validation errors as expected. However, I would like to redirect the user after the modal hide animation is finished if a condition is met based on a boolean held in the controller. Although the conditional wouldn't work as written, it lets you see what it is I am trying to accomplish:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modal-window').modal({remote: true});
  $('#modal-window').modal('show');
  $('#modal-window').on('hidden', function(){
    var saved = <%= @bool %>;
    if(saved == "true"){
      $(window.location.replace("<%= some_url %>"));}
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting saved to a boolean (probably - whatever is in your `@bool` var)

```
var saved = <%= @bool %>;
```

but then compare to the *string* `"true"`

```
if(saved == "true"){
```

so, if you replace the second line with

```
if(saved){
```

it'll work

Comment: whoops. thanks for pointing out the mistake. shweta's works too but this had a little more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
var saved = <%= @bool %>;
```

with

```
var saved = "<%= @bool %>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have this code posted? If your form is under `index.html.erb` then when using `remote: true`, you will want to have a `index.js.erb` file that will serve the javascript that you're looking to run in your example. Also, don't forget to escape the return URL with `j` like `<%=j some_url %>`.

Comment: Currently this in a <script> in the index.html.erb. I have the form updating any validation errors in the index.js.erb. Wouldn't I want the .on('hidden'... in the index.html.erb since it's going to be listening for the modal to finish closing to perform the redirect?

Comment: I'm new to js and i just don't know how to get a rails variable passed into the script above in order to make the conditional work.